# Does it makes sense to have a try statement before a class and the except statement after?

Tags: python

I found the following pattern in some Python code:

```
try:
    from foo import bar

    class MyClass:

        def __init__(self):
            ...

except ImportError:
    # Warning
```

Does it makes sense to place the `except` statement here? Can the `ImportError` occurs at another place than in the `from foo import bar` line?

Comment: It can't happen in a class but if the class should only be created if import works this is a convenient way to skip class creation and then handle the error (e.g. by creating a simpler variant of the class)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be really explicit (which is rarely a mistake), you could use the `try-except-else`  construct

```
try:
    from foo import bar
except ImportError:
    # Warning
else:
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            ...
```

but since - as you pointed - the `ImportError` will almost certainly be only raised by the import statement, you might as well include the class definition in the `try`-block for brevity's sake and one does see this pattern fairly often.